# Dimensions of a non-hermitian Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, open-quantum-systems

I have recently started studying the non-hermitian hamiltonians and I came across an example- $H=p^2+ix^3$ (where $h=1$ and $m=1/2$)
I know that hamiltonian is the total energy of the system. So how can it have term $x^3$? Woudn't it change the dimensionality?
ALso there are examples where the power of $x$ is $N$.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Some choice of units has been made to simplify the analysis of the problem.  You're already (presumably) comfortable with setting $\hbar=1$ and $m=1/2$; apparently some other constant in front of the $x^3$ term has also been set to 1.

If it makes you more comfortable, you can use
$$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + i\alpha x^3$$
for some constant $\alpha$ which has dimensions of energy over length cubed.  But all that will do is give you an extra symbol to write over and over and over again while you're learning a new theoretical framework.

Comment: Thanks for your help!